# Weak properties & prepareForSegue: one property becomes null and the other one not

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, weak-references, strong-references

I'm really confused about what happens in prepareForSegue at weak/strong properties. Let me explain:

I have **two simple view controller**:

- ViewController1
- ViewController2

connected with **one segue** from ViewController1 to ViewController2.

Both view controllers have two properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSArray *simpleArray;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *simpleString;
```

The thing that I can't understand is that **in my prepareForSegue the NSArray becomes null but the NSString not**. This is the code from ViewController1:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.simpleString = @"string";
    self.simpleArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"string2", @"string3", nil];

    NSLog(@"ViewDidLoad - simpleString: %@, simpleArray: %@", self.simpleString, self.simpleArray);
}


#pragma mark - segue

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"PrepareForSegue - simpleString: %@, simpleArray: %@", self.simpleString, self.simpleArray);

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue"])
    {
        ViewController2 *vc = (ViewController2 *)segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.simpleString = self.simpleString;
        vc.simpleArray = self.simpleArray;
    }
}
```

> 2015-07-07 17:23:12.915 test[3675:147600] ViewDidLoad - simpleString:
>   string, simpleArray: (
>       string2,
>       string3 )
>
> 2015-07-07 17:23:14.521 test[3675:147600] PrepareForSegue - simpleString: string, simpleArray: (null)

If I set the NSArray property as strong it maintain the value.

So, why two weak properties have a different behavior?

Comment: The real question is: why are these weak references and what are their owners?